# with fusiontables I want to show our delivery area's in google maps. But some country codes are not showing correct. How can I change this?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I tried to change the columns already, but that hasn't worked. I changed the GB to UK, but that doesnt work.

A sample of a country which is showing in the US, but is actually a GB delivery.

```
To City: Neewport NP204HH GB
To PostalCode: Neewport
To Country: NP204HH
Total ChargeBGB: GB
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you got the incorrect result, when I use `Neewport NP204HH GB` as value for a location-column I get a place in the UK(near Cardiff)

But when your geocoding-result isn't correct you may edit it.

- Click on the row to edit the values(a window opens), under the location-column you should see a link "edit geocode"(another window opens)
- type e.g. "Neewport" in the searchfield and search
- some markers should appear, find the marker at the desired location, and click on the marker->choose "use this location"
- click on "save"